# Generator "TypeError: 'generator' object is not an iterator"

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, multiprocessing

Due to the limitation of RAM memory, I followed [these](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) instructions and built a generator that draw small batch and pass them in the fit_generator of Keras.
But Keras can't prepare the queue with the multiprocessing even I inherit the Sequence.

Here is my generator for multiprocessing.

```
class My_Generator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_filenames, labels, batch_size):
        self.image_filenames, self.labels = image_filenames, labels
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return np.ceil(len(self.image_filenames) / float(self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.image_filenames[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

    return np.array([
        resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
           for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

The main function:

```
batch_size = 100
num_epochs = 10
train_fnames = []
mask_training = []
val_fnames = [] 
mask_validation = []
```

I would like that the generator read batches in the folders seperatly in different threads by IDs (where IDs look like: {number}.csv for raw images and {number}_label.csv for mask images). I initially built another more elegant class to stock every data in one .h5 file instead of directory. But blocked of the same problem. Thus, if you have a code to do this, I'm taker also.

```
for dirpath, _, fnames in os.walk('./train/'):
    for fname in fnames:
        if 'label' not in fname:
            training_filenames.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)))
        else:
            mask_training.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)))
for dirpath, _, fnames in os.walk('./validation/'):
    for fname in fnames:
        if 'label' not in fname:
            validation_filenames.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)))
        else:
            mask_validation.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)))


my_training_batch_generator = My_Generator(training_filenames, mask_training, batch_size)
my_validation_batch_generator = My_Generator(validation_filenames, mask_validation, batch_size)
num_training_samples = len(training_filenames)
num_validation_samples = len(validation_filenames)
```

Herein, the model is out of scope. I believe that it's not a problem of the model so I won't paste it.

```
mdl = model.compile(...)
mdl.fit_generator(generator=my_training_batch_generator,
              steps_per_epoch=(num_training_samples // batch_size),
              epochs=num_epochs,
              verbose=1,
              validation_data=None, #my_validation_batch_generator,
              # validation_steps=(num_validation_samples // batch_size),
              use_multiprocessing=True,
              workers=4,
              max_queue_size=2)
```

The error shows that the class I create is not an Iterator:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 141, in <module> max_queue_size=2)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2177, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 147, in fit_generator
generator_output = next(output_generator)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 831, in get six.reraise(value.__class__, value, value.__traceback__)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
TypeError: 'My_Generator' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: That's odd. You don't need to specify `steps_per_epoch` it is automatically calculated from `__len__` when you pass a `Sequence` object.

Comment: I can see the return statement in `def __getitem__(self, idx):` does not belong to the function. Is it a typo or you indeed have no return in it?

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko the idx might be something intrinsic of Keras' fit_generator. In the link, it's something dangling itself, too. I don't know much more details on it.

Comment: @nuric if I don't assign steps_per_epoch, I got `ValueError: 'steps_per_epoch=None' is only valid for a generator based on the 'keras.utils.Sequence' class. Please specify 'steps_per_epoch' or use the 'keras.utils.Sequence' class.` Error

Comment: That sounds like you are not inheriting from the correct `keras.utils.Sequence`. What is the super type of `My_Generator`?

Comment: @nuric When I do `My_Generator.__bases__`. It returns `<class 'keras.utils.data_utils.Sequence'>, `.

Comment: Apparently it's an open issue on TFs github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30089
. Downgrading your TF might solve the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?  I had the same issue.  I didn't need to implement the `__next__` method or change the base class of my generator as mentioned in current answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same problem, I managed to solve this by defining a `__next__` method:

```
class My_Generator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_filenames, labels, batch_size):
        self.image_filenames, self.labels = image_filenames, labels
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n = 0
        self.max = self.__len__()


    def __len__(self):
        return np.ceil(len(self.image_filenames) / float(self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.image_filenames[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
        resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
           for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n >= self.max:
           self.n = 0
        result = self.__getitem__(self.n)
        self.n += 1
        return result
```

note that I have declared two new variables in `__init__` function.

Comment: Why did you set `self.n = 0`?  Is this because we want to be able to loop through the data for each epoch?

Comment: generally you might want to train your model for a long time. this means that you might need to go through your data more than once. by setting the `self.n = 0`, you will ensure that the generator won't encounter an error when you reach the end of your data, it will only start over. Note that this doesn't necessarily mean looping through data at each epoch, but that is a possible case.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error saying my generator class which inherited from `keras.utils.Sequence` object `is not an iterator`.

Neither adding the `__next__` method nor changing between `keras.utils.Sequence` and `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` helped.

For me, my `__getitem__` class was not correctly implemented.  While trying to use all the data, the last batch was a partial batch which I was not handling correctly.  When I handled this correctly, the `object is not an iterator` error went away.  Thus, I suggest you carefully inspect your `__getitem__()` implementation and consider it for all `index` values passed to `__getitem__()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
My model was `from keras.models import Model`
However the generator was extended from `class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):`
That causes the bug!
So, just change the Generator `class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence)` to `class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):`

Comment: This did not fix the error 'object is not an iterator'.  Perhaps this error is related to `keras` and `tf` versions.