# Confusion regarding data generator in python for use in Keras fit_generator

Tags: python, keras

In some question and tutorials like below:

1. [Why is an iterable object not an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956034/why-is-an-iterable-object-not-an-iterator)
2. [Generator "TypeError: 'generator' object is not an iterator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590826/generator-typeerror-generator-object-is-not-an-iterator)

suggest that a data generator for keras should be a class having **__iter__** and **__next__** methods in it.

While some other tutorials like:

1. https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/tip-fit_generator-in-keras-how-to-parallelise-correctly/
2. https://www.altumintelligence.com/articles/a/Time-Series-Prediction-Using-LSTM-Deep-Neural-Networks

use the normal python function with a **yield** statement providing data. While I successfully used yield in an LSTM network following the second tutorial above, I am not able to use the normal yield function in a convolutional network and getting the below error in fit_generator:

> 'method' object is not an iterator

I haven't tried using the **__next__** method, but whoever got the above error was advised to use the **__next__** method (**EDIT:** working after a fix suggested by Daniel Möller). Can someone please help me clarify which technique to use when and what is the difference between a function that "**yields**" the next sample vs a class with **__iter__** & **__next__**?

My working code using yield:
https://github.com/KashyapCKotak/Multidimensional-Stock-Price-Prediction/blob/master/StockTF1_4Sequential.ipynb

My current data generator function using yield (**EDIT:** working after a fix suggested by Daniel Möller):

```
def train_images_generator(self):
    for epoch in range(0, self.epochs):
      print("Current Epoch:",epoch)
      cnt = 0
      if epoch > 2000:
        learning_rate = 1e-5

      for ind in np.random.permutation(len(self.train_ids)):
        print("provided image with id:",ind)
        #get the input image and target/ground truth image based on ind
        raw = rawpy.imread(in_path)
        input_images = np.expand_dims(pack_raw(raw), axis=0) * ratio # pack the bayer image in 4 channels of RGBG

        gt_raw = rawpy.imread(gt_path)
        im = gt_raw.postprocess(use_camera_wb=True,
                      half_size=False,
                      no_auto_bright=True, output_bps=16)
        gt_images = np.expand_dims(np.float32(im / 65535.0),axis=0) # divide by 65535 to normalise (scale between 0 and 1)

        # crop

        H = input_images.shape[1] # get the image height (number of rows)
        W = input_images.shape[2] # get the image width (number of columns)

        xx = np.random.randint(0, W - ps) # get a random number in W-ps (W-512)
        yy = np.random.randint(0, H - ps) # get a random number in H-ps (H-512)
        input_patch = input_images[:, yy:yy + ps, xx:xx + ps, :]
        gt_patch = gt_images[:, yy * 2:yy * 2 + ps * 2, xx * 2:xx * 2 + ps * 2, :]

        if np.random.randint(2) == 1:  # random flip for rows
          input_patch = np.flip(input_patch, axis=1)
          gt_patch = np.flip(gt_patch, axis=1)
        if np.random.randint(2) == 1:  # random flip for columns
          input_patch = np.flip(input_patch, axis=2)
          gt_patch = np.flip(gt_patch, axis=2)
        if np.random.randint(2) == 1:  # random transpose
          input_patch = np.transpose(input_patch, (0, 2, 1, 3))
          gt_patch = np.transpose(gt_patch, (0, 2, 1, 3))\

        input_patch = np.minimum(input_patch, 1.0)

        yield (input_patch,gt_patch)
```

How I use it:

```
model.fit_generator(
  generator=data.train_images_generator(),
  steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
  epochs=epochs,
  callbacks=callbacks,
  max_queue_size=50
  #workers=0
```

)

Comment: It's strange that with the change of architecture you are not able to generate data. These are almost two separate things. Could you please clarify your points by providing some codes showing how you are exactly doing it?

Comment: Actually instead of providing how I am doing it, I thought to provide the links where there is some discussion along with code examples. The way I am doing is the same as those in the examples in the links. (I have referred these links to make the generator)

Comment: will update the code after trying the "next" method. But was just curious to ask why even its required in the first place when some given examples work with yield.

Comment: @today Have added the code. request you to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking carefully at the word `'method'`, I see you are not "calling" your generator (you are not creating it).

You are passing just the function/method.

Suppose you have:

```
def generator(...):
    ...
    yield x, y
```

Instead of something like:

```
model.fit_generator(generator)
```

You should do something like:

```
model.fit_generator(generator(...))
```

---

### Generator or Sequence

What is the difference between using a generator (a function with `yield`) and a `keras.utils.Sequence`?

When using a generator, training will follow the exact loop order, and it will not know when to finish. So.

**With a generator:**

- Cannot shuffle batches because it will always follow the order of the loop
- Must inform `steps_per_epoch` because Keras cannot know when the generator has finished (generators for Keras must be infinite)
- If using multiprocessing, the system may not handle the batches correctly because it's impossible to know which process will start or finish before the others.

**With a `Sequence`:**

- You control the length of the generator. Keras knows the number of batches automatically
- You control the indexing of the batches, so Keras can shuffle batches.
- You can take whatever batch you want how many times you want (you are not forced to take batches in sequence)
- Multiprocessing can use the indices to make sure the batches are not going to be mixed in the end.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is right and it partially solved my issue. Partially because I also need to know the difference in yield and other methods mentioned in the question. Does it mean methods with yield can be used instead of extending keras.util.Sequence or a class with iter and next functions? or is there any important difference between them? I'll accept once you answer this question. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMoller I have a kind of similar question that generates sequences. I am currently using a LSTM model for it. Please let me know your thoughts. Link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978301/how-to-use-deep-learning-for-time-series-forecasting I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much. :)