# python code not working for excel but working for csv files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have written a code which is working properly for csv files but if I change the file type from csv to excel its giving me an error.

I have, `data = pd.read_excel(filename)` the above lines is not working for excel if I write `data = pd.read_csv(filename)`, its working properly. And I want my input data in excel not csv.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import xlrd

def latlong_func(filename):
    # filename instead of r'C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/Gap1.csv'
    data = pd.read_excel(filename)

    #df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['SUPPLIER_ID','ACTION'])

    data["latlong"] = 'FALSE'
    data.loc[
        (data["LONGITUDE"] >= 70.0000) & (data["LONGITUDE"] <= 98.0000) &
        (data["LONGITUDE"] != 'nan') & (data["LATITUDE"] != 'nan')&
        (data["LATITUDE"] >= 6.0000) & (data["LATITUDE"] <= 36.000),
        ["latlong"]] = ''

    data.to_csv("practice1.csv")

    writer = data[data["latlong"]=='']
    writer.to_csv('newfile1.csv')
    writer.to_csv('latlong1.csv')

    print("Kindly ignore the message..your output is genrated sucessfully....")



     def get_filename():


      filename = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('Python Files', '*.xlsx')])

      if filename:
         lbl['text'] = filename # display filename in Label
         latlong_func(filename)
     else:
         lbl['text'] = 'not selected'


    # --- main ---

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x100')

    lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename')
    lbl.pack(side='top', pady=10)

    btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=get_filename)
    btn.pack(side='top', pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Somebody please help me to know where I am doing wrong.
I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patesari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2890, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'LONGITUDE'
```

Comment: What is the `data` dataframe returned when using `data = pd.read_excel(filename)`? My guess is that you're not reading in what you're expecting.

Comment: Is 'LONGITUDE' a column name for your dataframe? If you Excel file has a title or spaces, it could pick the wrong row as the columns. Try to print(data.columns) after reading excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check your excel file extension
suppose 
if `filename=file.csv` then `data=pd.read_csv(filename)` will work

OR

if `filename=file.xlsx` then `data=pd.read_excel(filename)` will work

And If you want input data in excel not csv then 
convert .csv to .xlsx by using below code and then pick that converted file 
and use `data=pd.read_csv(filename)` to read your excel file

```
export_excel = df.to_excel ('file_path_to_save', index = None, header=True)#Don't forget to add '.xlsx' at the end of the path
```

Hope this will work for you

if my answer provide you solution please vote thanks

Comment: i made a proper new excel file.and now i am getting this error 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: it would be convenient if you post your code and error message

Answer (score 0):

KeyError: 'LONGITUDE'

- Pandas **excel** parsing and **csv** parsing will vary. Having said that try to see the difference between both method calls by printing "data"
- If your file extensions are proper, then I would recommend you to try with other xlsx parser libraries like "pyexcel" (You can both read/write using this library). [http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest](http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/)/. You will be able to see how table data from your excel is changed into varying data structures like "list of list" or "list of tuples", etc.

Comment: its giving me this error:   latlong_func(filename)
  File "latlong final.py", line 16, in latlong_func
    (data["LATITUDE"] >= 6.0000) & (data["LATITUDE"] <= 36.000)]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I think you messing up your data structures with the hurry of just fixing the errors. Please know what and how you are using your parsed data beforehand. The errors you are posting are very much standard errors you can get them online. For this particular case visit -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590826/generator-typeerror-generator-object-is-not-an-iterator. Recommending you to use/test your code using **ipython** before writing it in one shot.